# How to show that $x-x^2$ is bounded if $x$ is?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)=x-x^2$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that if $|x|<B$, then $|f(x)|
<B'$ for some $B'$.

I tried the following:

If $|x|<B$ then, $-B<x<B$. So, $1-B<1-x<1+B$. Now, I cannot multiply $x$ and $1-x$ because it depends on the sign of $B$. How can I continue?

Comment: combine the two following facts : 

$$|x^2| = |x|^2 \leq B^2$$

and 

$$|x-x^2| \leq |x| + |x^2|$$

Comment: Or use the fact that the continuous image of a compact set is compact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Show that if $|x|<B$, then $|1-x|<B+1$.
- Use the fact that $|a||b|=|ab|$ with $a=x$, $b=1-x$.

Answer (score 3):

Using the triangle inequality:
$$
 |f(x)| = | x - x^2| \le |x | + |x^2| = |x | + |x|^2 < \ldots ?
$$

The triangle inequality becomes an equality for $x \le 0$, so this gives a sharp bound $B'$.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that by the triangle inequality:
$$ |x + -x^2|\leq |x| + |-x^2|= |x|+ |x|^2$$
We know that $x$ is bounded so for some bound $|x|< B$
$$ |x -x^2|\leq|x|+ |x|^2 < B + B^2 $$
We conclude that $x-x^2$ is bounded by $B'$ where $B'= B+B^2$.

---

Alternatively, we could use the **extreme value theorem.** This states that any continuous function on a closed interval in $\mathbb R$ attains its maximum and minimum.

Notice that $f(x) = x - x^2$ is a continuous function on any interval in $\mathbb R$.  then by the extreme value theorem, if $x\in [-B, B]$  this means that on this interval the maximum and minimum is attained, we denote the largest of these two in absolute value by $B'$, we then get
$$ |f(x)| < B'$$
As desired.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{eqnarray}
-B &\le& x\le B\\
-B^2&\le& -x^2\le 0\\
-B^2-B&\le&x-x^2 \le B\\
|x-x^2|&\le&\max\{B,|B^2+B|\}\\
|x-x^2|&\le&B^2+B
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 2):

$-B <x<+B.$

Consider the interval $I:= [-B,B];$

The continuous function $f(x)=x-x^2$ attains its maximum and minimum on the compact interval $I$.

Choose

$B'=\max (|min_I f|, |\max_I f| )$.